# React | error "Objects are not valid as a React child" when trying to push to state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning some React with a project I dreamed up that has data being passed via props and also pubsub messages.
I'm passing an email address via pubsub and it comes in fine on the pubsub subscribe method, like this:

```
myEmailChannel.subscribe("email", (msg) => {
            let data = msg.data;
            
            console.log(data);
                         
        });
```

The above results in a console log of

```
value: 'test@test.com'
```

test@test.com being a fake test email that I sent via pubsub.
The problem happens when I try to add the data to an already initialized state array of "emails", I get some crazy error about "**Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**"
I am trying something like:

```
 myEmailChannel.subscribe("email", (msg) => {
            let data = msg.data;
            
            console.log(data);
            let emails = [...this.state.emails];
            emails.push({ value: data });
            this.setState({emails});
            
        });
```

only to get the aforementioned error. Actually, it happens no matter how I try to add the data to the array. I think I understand that I'm just formatting the incoming data incorrectly for the state array?
Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I followed the error a little further and it says the error occurs when it tries to iterate over the array for display:

```
{this.state.emails.map((email, index) => {
                return (

                    <li key={index}>{email}</li>

                );
            })}
```

Comment: 1) How is the `emails` state being used then? 2) `data = {value: 'test@test.com'}` but you are doing `emails.push({ value: data });` So basically you are doing `emails.push({ value:  {value: 'test@test.com'}});`

Comment: 1) I just plan to iterate the array to list items with map. 2) AH this may be my issue, and I suspected it might be. Will comment back.

Comment: @MatthewKwong just added some more info. Apparently it has a problem with the data being passed vs the way I am iterating over it for display. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, `email` is an object. When you do something like this

```
this.state.emails.map((email, index) => (
  <li key={index}>{email}</li>
))
```

React gets confused. It doesn't know whether it should treat the `email` object as a string (which is properly what you are trying to do), or render it as a component.

You can do something like this instead.

```
this.state.emails.map((email, index) => (
  <li key={index}>{email.value}</li>
))
```

Comment: This was it. I was pretty sure I had my mapping wrong and couldn't figure out exactly where. Thanks so much I can quit pulling my hair out.